# Can not launch local Vaadin test site

Tags: java, apache, intellij-idea, jetty, vaadin

I am having trouble launching my test Vaadin site on my MacBook. When I try to open the port 8080 in Safari it opens an old Vaadin project of mine. IntelliJ keeps telling me this.

```
[INFO] Started o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@162c1dfb{/,file:///Users/jackson/proghub/assignment5/src/main/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{file:///Users/jackson/proghub/assignment5/src/main/webapp/}
[INFO] Jetty server exiting.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.285 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-13T12:22:16-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 46M/381M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.9.v20160517:run (default-cli) on project assignment5: Failure: Address already in use -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Clearly the problem is:

> Failure: Address already in use

What should I do about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick a different port.

Port 8080 is in use by some other process.

Perhaps you can alter your testing to use port 0 (system allocated dynamic port) instead.  Wait for the server to start, figure out its port number, and use that in your testing.

Comment: I ended up just restarting my computer and that worked. If the problem persisted I would have tried to change ports. Thanks for the feedback anyway.